# Routine pointer to struct with struct as parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a chicken and the egg problem. I want to pass a data struct to a routine which contains a pointer to a routine who needs the struct.

I made a very simple example.

I need to use the CalcDataStruct before it's defined, if I add it after the struct, the FuntctionPrototype is not defined.

The problem i run against is only in the first 2 lines, the rest may contain a few syntax errors because I have not checked this inside the compiler.

```
typedef void(*FunctionPrototype)(CalcDataStruct *Ptr);

struct CalcDataStruct 
{
  int A, B, C, D;
  int Values;
  char SignA, Sign B;
  int Result;
  FunctionPrototype Routine;
}


struct ScanStruct
{
  char Sign; 
  int Values;
  FunctionPrototype Routine;
};


const ScanStruct ExampleList[] =
{
   { '+', 2, AddTwo },
   { '+', 3, AddThree }
};

void AddTwo(CalcDataStruct *Ptr)
{
  // use the data and if needed put it back
}

void AddThree(CalcDataStruct *Ptr)
{
  // use the data and if needed put it back
}

void GetFunction(CalcDataStuct *Ptr, ScanStruct *List)
{
   // Very simple return based on nothing
   Ptr->Routine = *List[(1)].Routine;
}   

void main()
{
   CalcDataStruct A;
   // struct is filled

   // Fill in the routine pointer based on data
  GetFunction(A, ExampleList)
  // Execute the routine fetched with all the data
  A->Routine(A)
}
```

Comment: Is this a C or a C++ question? Please pick at most one.

Comment: Removed the C tag. However solution is valid for both.

Comment: That's likely but cannot be said in advance. Some things work in C that don't work in C++ and vice versa. That's why it's policy that you ask about one language at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a forward declaration (see below).

`struct CalcDataStruct;` will just declare that `struct CalcDataStruct` exists, so the `typedef void(*FunctionPrototype)(CalcDataStruct *Ptr);` declaration will succeed because now the compiler knows that `struct CalcDataStruct` exists but without knowing the details of the struct, which doesn't matter because all the `FunctionPrototype` declaration needs is to know that the parameter is a pointer to `struct CalcDataStruct`.

```
struct CalcDataStruct; // <<< add this

typedef void(*FunctionPrototype)(CalcDataStruct *Ptr);

struct CalcDataStruct 
{
  int A, B, C, D;
  int Values;
  char SignA, Sign B;
  int Result;
  FunctionPrototype Routine;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, sometimes looking at the answer makes me think however could i not have thought about this myself.